# VB.net Google Map retrieve data info from database

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps

I am using google map API to show the map and some marker. When a user clicks on the marker, it will show the location info. Those info I store inside database. How can retrieve the data when the marker has been clicked? Because the google map code is in javascript, how to link with vb behind code?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this is to create the overlay KML file with all the information at the outset. The info gets displayed when the user click on the marker.

The way to do this is to create a KML file and put it on a public webserver, then in Google Maps put the URL for the KML file in the Google Maps search box, and it will render the entire map with the placemarks.

Comment: What you mean overlay KML file?